# How do I get conky to display the CPU frequency per core in GHz?

Tags: cpu, conky, cpuinfo

I am trying to get Conky to display the CPU frequency per core, but it only displays it for the first one. I know I can get a frequency in MHz, but how would I get it in GHz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [list of variables](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html), you need to use the `freq_g` variable instead of `freq` to display in GHz instead of MHz.

Also, as per the documentation, to show each core separately you would add multiple entries like `${freq_g 1}` or `${freq_g 32}`, depending on how many cores you have.

Comment: Yes, but this still only shows the frequency of the first core. I need to show the frequency of each core. I have 2 cores and 4 threads, so it only shows the frequency of the first core.

Comment: It shows the frequency of the core matching the number in the entry.  0, 1, 2, 3 are the ones to use, in separate entries, for a quad-core (or quad-thread) CPU.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I had set it wrong, using 1, 2, 3, 4 before  but this worked.

Comment: Apparently it counts from 1, not 0.

Comment: @ZeissIkon As it indicates in the linked documentation, CPU cores are addressed >= 1 for each core, and `0` has a special meaning for _average of all cores combined_.

Comment: Sigh.  Not at home, so couldn't look at my own `conky.rc` to check.